# Log in as different user using asp.net windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, firefox

I have created a asp.net web application and have used windows authentication, for testing purposes i want to use the application as a different user.

I thought running firefox as a different user would achieve this but doing this does not seem to work.  The HttpContext.Current.User property is still logged in AD user.

Is there a setting or anything i need to change in firefox to fix this?

Comment: i log onto the machine using AD.  Then when i run the application it sets the HttpContext.Current.User property to whatever i logged in as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an very easy option for every program. Use [RUNAS](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command. Open cmd and type:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\USER "c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can configure the "Integrated windows authentication" in fireFox in the `about:config` page.

Please take a look at the following [link](http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/). This link is to activate the integrated authentication but maybe you can use it to do the revert operation.

Once FireFox ask you for username and password you will be able to enter a different from yours (logged one).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to much about firefox, but there is a setting under IE properties (which I think most other browsers derive security settings from).  "Automatic login for intranet sites" - or something to that effect, needs to be turned off and it should then start to prompt you for login details.